# Defining folder for compiled object files in Gradle for a C project?

Tags: gcc, gradle, build.gradle

How can I change the default location of the folder in which the compiled object files are stored when using Gradle for compiling c sources?

Right now, the objects are created in `build/objs/path/of/object_files`. How do i change it to some location within my source file hierarchy? And how do i convey this information the linker (if required)?

Also as a note, I do not use the default Gradle convention source file hierarchy. And I use GCC compiler and linker (sparc-rtems variant).

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think it is possible as this will go directly against Gradle model design.**

The whole point of the new software model in Gradle is to be declarative. Model should only describe what needs to be done, not how. Once you need to access the object files, you need to know implementation details.